# xcode 5.0.2 boolean values being confused

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, boolean

I am using Xcode 5.0.2 and seeing some strange behaviour for bool.
When I evaluate a bool returned from a method, I see it as false when I hover over it. However, it enters the true branch of the if statement. When I change the code to

```
 if(validWord == false)
```

and execute the code again, it jumps to the else branch. (shows value as false but interprets as true) It seems to be evaluating the opposite of the bool value.

[image: boolActingStrange]

When I change the code to test for validWord == false

if (validWord == false)

and execute the code again, it jumps to the else branch. (evaluates as true) It seems to be evaluating the opposite of the bool value.

[image]

Has anyone experienced this behaviour?

ADDITION:
Even when I use BOOL, the same behaviour is apparent.
[image]

I added some NSLOG entries to test the value of validWord;

[image]

It returns 1 for

```
 NSLog(@"validWord: %i", validWord);
```

and returns YES for

```
 NSLog(@"result is :%@",((validWord==YES)?@"YES":@"NO"));
```

while showing a value of NO when you hover over the variable validWord in Xcode.
I will try madmik3's suggestion.

Comment: My guess would be that what the debugger popup is saying is wrong and the value of validWord is in fact true. This could happen if you are running the code in release mode without debug symbols which can make values default to nil.

Comment: You are mixing different idioms from different languages here.  `BOOL`, `YES`, and `NO` are Objective-C.  `bool`, `true`, and `false` are C/C++.  Also, you are comparing with `true` and `false`, which is a bad idea in general.  If you switch your code to use Objective-C consistently and don't compare directly with `true` or `false`, do the same issues arise?

Comment: Three questions: 1) In the last image, where the debugger says that `validWord` is `NO`, does the true-branch of the if statement run (i.e. does `[self unschedule:...]` run?)
2) What is the output if you put this line right above `if(validWord)`: `NSLog(@"validWord: %i", validWord);`?
3) What is the method signature of `getCurrentWord`?

Comment: Johannes, 1)True branch runs. 2) It returns an int value of 1 3) Method was previously returning bool but changed it to BOOL to be consistent with the third screen capture, and it still enters valid branch of if statement.

Comment: This is an usual problem.  Can you please paste the code in, rather than using screenshots - the only feasible explanation I can think of is a stray `;` character after `if (validWord)`.  Pasting the code would reveal that.

Comment: Xcode may just be confused and showing you the wrong thing. That happens sometimes. Also, do you have a member variable or global variable named `validWord`? If so, it may just be showing you the value of the one whose scope is hidden in this case.

Comment: Off-topic: it's bad form to call a method that "checks whether word in dictionary" `getCurrentWord`. How about making it a property with a name like `inDictionary`, corresponding to a getter method called `isInDictionary`?

Answer (score 0):

You may not realise that, but there is a huge difference between bool and BOOL.

BOOL is a signed char. It therefore can have values from -128 to +127. If you convert an int to BOOL, the compiler just takes the last 8 bits.

bool is a type defined by the C language. It can only have values 0 and 1. If you convert an int to bool, the compiler produces 0 = false if the int was zero, and 1 = true if the int was non-zero.

Check what the method returns that you changed from returning bool to BOOL.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. With Xcode 6. When tried to get some value from NSUserDefaults. Relaunch didn't help. So i found work around. 
**Solution**
Launch Simulator and then simply reset contents and settings.